# Sentence order prediction from user given input using RNN- LSTM language modeling

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to Deep learning and python. My task is to predict the sequence of the sentence from the words given by user.
 I have seen a lot of articles on word prediction and very few in sentence prediction which gave me idea of how to randomly predicts in a sentence but I have to generate semantically correct sentences for my project from specific input.

Please help me as concepts are clear to me but i am finding it difficult to code.The link pointing to tensorflow tutorial explains a language model. It is designed to predict the next word given the previous context information. And a trained model will fluently print out meaningful sentences.

I want to build a language model to "predict the sequence of the sentence from the words".  for example if user inputs "apple eats man" my language model should be able to produce a semantically correct sentence i-e "man eats apple".

Answer (score -1):

Note: this suggestion is from what I have seen from webpages and papers. What you can do is that you can replace periods, question marks, exclamations etc with some end of sentence marker(a word) like `EOS`. Predictions until an `EOS` prediction can be considered as a sentence.

**EDIT:**
Take a look at this [link](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/). Skip to section three

Comment: It might be that a user did not find your answer useful. Also note that this question is receiving close votes, because it is too broad for Stack Overflow. If you fear receiving these downvotes, it would be best for you to answer good quality, on-topic questions instead.